# Datatables Expand All on multiple pages functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am implementing a expand all Functionality of all rows in datatable. I have the functionality implemented for a each individual row in the datatable with a + sign, when you click there the row expands. each row has a onclick javascript function. 
While implementing expand all All the rows in page 1 gets expanded. But on page 2 the rows stay closed. What should i be doing so that the onclick function gets called on page 2 as well. Here is my code for expand all.

```
jQuery('body').on('click','#ExpandAll ',function(){

    var rows = jQuery("#sortable_mappedTable").dataTable();
     jQuery.each(rows.fnGetNodes(), function (i, row) {
         var id = jQuery(this).find('.dataToggle.dataToggleClosed').trigger("onclick");
     });

});
```

Comment: I would appreciate some help on this. Thanks to all who take time to respond

Comment: please show a sample of your markup too ...